# Nextjs - server action - experimental_useFormStatus

Tags: next.js, vercel

Im trying to use the experimental server actions from next js (I have set that flag to true in the config).

I made an app using [this repo](https://github.com/steven-tey/prisma-server-actions).

When I run this in development mode, I can post to prisma. When I try to deploy it to Vercel, it fails with an error that says:

> "react-dom"' has no exported member 'experimental_useFormStatus'

Does anyone know how to deploy experimental features?

Answer (score 0):

experimental_useFormStatus is in experimental state and it allowed only in client component.i have used this experimental_useFormStatus in my application and it is working fine. code is given below. add-product.ts code

```
import FormSubmitButton from "@/components/FormSubmitButton"
import prisma from "@/lib/db/prisma"
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Add Product Ecommerce',
    description: 'Adding new product using server actions in next js 13 app router',
  }
    const addProduct=async(formData:FormData)=>{
        "use server"
        const name=formData.get("name")?.toString()
        const description=formData.get("description")?.toString()
        const imageUrl=formData.get("imageUrl")?.toString()
        const price=Number(formData.get("price")||0)
        if(!name || !price|| !description || !imageUrl){
            throw Error("Fields Are Empty")
        }
        await prisma.product.create({data:{name,description,imageUrl,price}})
        redirect("/")
    }
    export default function AddProductPage(){
    return(
        <div className=" h-screen flex flex-col  
        items-center justify-center w-full">
            <h1 className="lg:text-2xl text-xl mb-3 font-bold">Add Product</h1>
            <form action={addProduct} className="shadow w-full py-4 m-2">
                <div className="flex flex-col mb-2  md:flex-row md:mr-2 items-center  justify-start md:justify-center w-full ">
                    <label className="md:w-1/6 w-1/2 ">Enter Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" className="input input-bordered w-1/2" placeholder="Enter Product Name" />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col mb-2  md:flex-row md:mr-2 items-center  justify-start md:justify-center w-full ">
                    <label className="md:w-1/6 w-1/2 ">Enter Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="price" className="input input-bordered w-1/2" placeholder="Enter Product Price" />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col mb-2  md:flex-row md:mr-2 items-center  justify-start md:justify-center w-full ">
                    <label className="md:w-1/6 w-1/2 ">Enter Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" className="input input-bordered w-1/2" placeholder="Enter Product Description" />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col mb-2  md:flex-row md:mr-2 items-center  justify-start md:justify-center w-full ">
                    <label className="md:w-1/6 w-1/2 ">Enter Image Url</label>
                <input type="text" name="imageUrl" className="input input-bordered w-1/2" placeholder="Enter Image Url" />
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center md:mx-56 mx-0 justify-center md:justify-start">
                    <FormSubmitButton className="" >Add Product</FormSubmitButton>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
    }
```

FormSubmitButton.tsx client component code
"use client"
import React, { ComponentProps } from 'react'
import { experimental_useFormStatus } from 'react-dom';

```
type FormSubmitButtonProps={
  children:React.ReactNode,
  className?:string,
} & ComponentProps<"button">

const FormSubmitButton = ({children,className,...props}:FormSubmitButtonProps) => {
  const { pending } = experimental_useFormStatus()
  return (
    <button 
    {...props }
    className={'btn btn-accent text-slate-700 ${className}'}
    disabled={pending}
    type="submit">
      {pending && <span className="loading loading-dots loading-lg text-center"/>}
      {children}
      </button>
  )
}

export default FormSubmitButton
```